# Calling component on main page in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am having some trouble with knockoutjs components, I'm following the example in the [official knockout component documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html).

How can I call my widget component on the main page? I think I may be putting the code in the wrong places.

**Code:**
**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/knockout/knockout-3.3.0.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/widget.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
ko.components.register('like-or-dislike', {
    viewModel: { require: 'files/widget' },
    template: { require: 'text!files/widget.html' }
});

alert(ko.components.isRegistered('like-or-dislike'));
```

**widget.html**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: products">
    <li class="product">
        <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
        <like-widget params="value: userRating"></like-widget>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**widget.js**

```
function Product(name, rating) {
    this.name = name;
    this.userRating = ko.observable(rating || null);
}

function MyViewModel() {
    this.products = [
        new Product('Garlic bread'),
        new Product('Pain au chocolat'),
        new Product('Seagull spaghetti', 'like') // This one was already 'liked'
    ];
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

Comment: Just add `<like-or-dislike></like-or-dislike>` to your html.

Comment: The example uses `require.js` to load the viewmodel and template, but you are not using it in your html.

Comment: Do you want to have your widget constructor and template in a separate files? If so then you will need to use `require.js` as the example and Dandy have suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as you lost track a little bit when the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) explains how to load components from external files using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).

> I think I may be putting the code in the wrong places

Yes, you have indeed misplaced some of the code. Let's get you back on track : )

**Firstly**, the code in your *widget.js* belongs in your *main.js* along with the call to `ko.components.register`.

**Secondly**, the markup you have in *widget.html*, for your view model, belongs in *index.html*.

**Thirdly**, you seem to be missing the code and markup for the widget itself.

Take a look at the working example below. I've put which file each bit of code belongs in in the comments above the code.

You will **not** need to define the module names by passing them in  as the first argument into the *requirejs* `define` function like I have:

```
define("files/widget",...
define("main",...
```

This is only there to work in the [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers). *requirejs* uses a convention based on file paths if the module name is not supplied, for example requirejs will look for a file called *widget.js* in a folder called *files* when given the module name `files/widget`. Please read the [requirejs docs](http://requirejs.org/).

```js
// This goes in widget.html, only the html. 
// This example uses the define function only to work in this snippet.
define("text!files/widget.html", [], function() {
  return '<div class="like-or-dislike" data-bind="visible: !chosenValue()">\
            <button data-bind="click: like">Like it</button>\
            <button data-bind="click: dislike">Dislike it</button>\
        </div>\
        <div class="result" data-bind="visible: chosenValue">\
            You <strong data-bind="text: chosenValue"></strong> it\
        </div>'
});

// This goes in in widget.js, you must use the define function. 
define("files/widget", [], function() {
  return function(params) {
    // Data: value is either null, 'like', or 'dislike'
    this.chosenValue = params.value;

    // Behaviors
    this.like = function() {
      this.chosenValue('like');
    }.bind(this);
    this.dislike = function() {
      this.chosenValue('dislike');
    }.bind(this);
  }
});

// all of the below goes into main.js
require.config({
  paths: {
    "knockout": "http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.3.0",
    "text": "https://rawgit.com/requirejs/text/master/text"
  }
});

define("main", ["knockout"], function(ko) {
  ko.components.register('like-or-dislike', {
    viewModel: {
      require: 'files/widget'
    },
    template: {
      require: 'text!files/widget.html'
    }
  });

  function Product(name, rating) {
    this.name = name;
    this.userRating = ko.observable(rating || null);
  }

  function MyViewModel() {
    this.products = [
      new Product('Garlic bread'),
      new Product('Pain au chocolat'),
      new Product('Seagull spaghetti', 'like') // This one was already 'liked'
    ];
  }

  ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
})
```

```html
<!-- this goes in the body of index.html -->
<ul data-bind="foreach: products">
  <li class="product">
    <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
    <like-or-dislike params="value: userRating"></like-or-dislike>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.19/require.min.js" data-main="main"></script>
```

Comment: This is not the right approach if you are using `require.js` putting every thing in a single file. The 'widget.html` should not be included in `index.html` file, neither should be defined as module. The `require.js text plugin` will load and inject it when required.

Comment: @Dandy everything is in a single file to get the example working in the snippet. If you look at the documentation OP is following, what OP has in *widget.html* is not actually the component markup it is the markup that calls the component. So yes this should be in *index.html*.

Comment: answer seems right but it in is in a single file. not sure which part goes where.

Comment: @MikePhils I've updated the answer. I've put comments in the code to say which bit of code belongs in which file.